# Rails saving external event ID from external API for subsequent calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been developing on Ruby on Rails for a while and this is the first time I ran into this problem. We're using an external API to allow users to open an account with them. They have an API endpoint for us to use and check account statuses and it has a limit of only 1000 events that will be sent back to us. In order to avoid that limit, we'd have to send over the last event ID that we processed so they will only send back events after that event.

For example, we just processed event with ID `10,000`. Sending that as a param to their API endpoint will give us back events with ID `10,001 or greater`.

What is the best way to keep track of this ID? The only way I can think of is to make a model with column `external_id` and keep updating that one record after everything's been processed. This does not seem like the best way to deal with this to me since I'm creating a new model with only 1 record, which seems like a weird thing to do.

I'm calling their API and processing it in a rake task that runs every 1 minute through a cronjob (using the `whenever` gem).

I don't mean to be subjective, I just want to know if there are any better way to handle this situation than the one I can think of right now before I go ahead and implement it. Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT: Here's how their response would look like:

```
[  
     {  
        "id":1087105,
        "dateTime":"2017-01-03T15:38:58.003Z",
        "payload":"{  
            \"status\":\"PENDING\",
            \"requestId\":\"4ab7f930-cf9f-49c2-9814-3bcc2f29e652\"
        }"
     },
     {  
        "id":1087106,
        "dateTime":"2017-01-03T15:38:58.253Z",
        "payload":"{  
            \"status\":\"INVESTIGATION_SUBMITTED\",
            \"requestId\":\"4ab7f930-cf9f-49c2-9814-3bcc2f29e652\"
        }"
    }
]
```

The field I'd need to save is the last `"id"` in that response, in this case that would be `1087106`.

Comment: Before that, help me understand, if you send them the recent ID in the param, in response what do you get ? An array of events or just one element ? If you only want to track the ID, when the new ID comes back in the response what happens to the existing one ? Are you thinking of creating a new ActiveRecord object with that ID ? If so, I would suggest using something like redis and store them as pairs, everytime you get a new ID, you can just update the key. However, another question is, how do you associate the ID to which record it belongs to ?

Comment: It would send me back an array of events, each would have their own ID with new events having bigger ID. I have to save the ID of the last event they give me so next time, I can send that ID to them and they'd only give back the events that happen after the event with the ID I gave. This is so that I don't have to process duplicate data and avoid their limit cap of 1000 events per request.

Comment: Ok, all that matters is the last ID only right ? So you can go ahead and use redis and store it as a pair and in the next response when you get the new array based on old ID, just update the same key with the recent ID.

Comment: Yeah, I just finished doing some research on Redis and this seems like the best option for me. Thanks for helping out! Just a quick question, do you know if the Redis pair expire? I couldn't find any information on that and that's my only concern right now, otherwise it looks like exactly what I need

Comment: Are you asking, if a key can expiry, like within a time period ?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid that it will expire and will throw some unexpected errors when I try to get the key

Comment: By default, in redis all objects have an expiration, but if you don't set the object to expire, that time is "never". For a detailed explanation on how redis handles check [this](https://redis.io/commands/expire).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a great job for a simple key-value store like Redis; particularly it's counting feature, `INCRBY`. This article http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/take-advantage-of-redis-adding-it-to-your-stack.html explains various scenarios where you would want to use redis. The section on `Counting stuff` fits your problem definition.